# PHP template function not returning data

Tags: php, function

I made a basic PHP template system made of **controllers/pages.php** and **views/pages.php**. The **views** uses the **controller** to populate the HTML with data that should be coming from the **controller**, however some data is not being passed from **controller** to **views** I marked the code below with comments as such "**# ==> NOT WORKING**" anything with such comment does not return any data to **views** any suggestion as to possibly why?

```
<?php

# THIS IS CONTROLLERS/PAGES.PHP

class Page {
    private $title, $stylesheets=array(), $javascripts=array(), $body;

    # ==> NOT WORKING
    function Site() {
        $site = "http://dev.site.tld/";
        return $site;
    }

    function Page() {
        $this->addCSS('css/main.css');
        $this->addCSS('css/font-awesome.css');
        $this->addJavascript('js/jquery.js');
        $this->addJavascript('js/application-build102121.js');
    }

    function setTitle($title) {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    # ==> NOT WORKING
    function setCopyright() {
         $copyright_year = date("Y");
         return $copyright_year;
    }

    # ==> NOT WORKING
    function setAppName() {
         $app_name = "Latte";
         return $app_name;
    }

    function addCSS($path) {
        $this->stylesheets[] = $path;
    }

    # ==> NOT WORKING
    function listCSS($path) {   
        $data = Site(); 
        foreach ($this->stylesheets as $stylesheet) {
             echo '<link href="' . $data . $stylesheet . '" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />' . "\n";
        }
        return $this;   
    }

    # ==> NOT WORKING
    function listJS($path) {
        $data = Site();
        foreach ($this->javascripts as $javascript) {
             echo '<script src="' . $data . $javascript . '" type="text/javascript" defer="defer"></script>' . "\n";
         }  
        return $this;
    }

    function addJavascript($path) {
        $this->javascripts[] = $path;
    }


    function startBody() {
        ob_start();
    }

    function endBody() {
        $this->body = ob_get_clean();
    }

    function render($path) {
        ob_start();
        include($path);
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

Error_Reporting returns

```
Notice: Undefined property: Page::$listCSS in /home/adminis1/public_html/dev/views/pages.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined property: Page::$listJS in /home/adminis1/public_html/dev/views/pages.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined property: Page::$setCopyright in /home/adminis1/public_html/dev/views/pages.php on line 25
```

The way data is called
Index.php

```
<?php
require_once('controllers/pages.php');
$page = new Page;
$page->setTitle('Home');
$page->startBody();
?>

<img src="test-img.jpg" />

<?php
$page->endBody();
echo $page->render('views/pages.php');
```

VIEWS/PAGES.PHP

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><?php echo $this-setAppName; ?> - <?php echo $this->title; ?></title>

    <!-- view port meta -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">


    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <?php echo $this->listCSS; ?>

    <?php echo $this->listJS; ?>

</head>
<body>

    <?php echo $this->body; ?>

    <footer>
        <p>Copyright &copy; <?php echo $this->setCopyright; ?> </p>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `return this` — do you mean `return $this`?

Comment: @MCEmperor Ahe did not catch that I missed $ before this, actually I fixed it to return $this still not data being returned for setAppName, setCopyright, listCSS and listJS

Comment: How did you test (the contents of) the variables? Using `var_dump()`?

Comment: @MCEmperor I think I know whats causing the problem error_reporting returns Undefined property: Page::$listCSS @ views/pages.php on line 15 and Undefined property: Page::$listJS @ views/pages.php on line 17 same for setCopyright on line 25

Comment: I don't see any construction of a Page instance anywhere, using the keyword `new`.

Comment: @MCEmperor are you talking about the new updated post? I added code for index.php and views/pages.php

Comment: Okay, I see. See my answer for possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling methods like it were properties.

Change `$this->setCopyright` to `$this->setCopyright()` and so on.

```
class Page {
    private $title;

    function setCopyright() {
        ...
    }
}

$page = new Page();
```

`$title` is a property, access it through `$page->title`.
`setCopyright()` is a function, access it through `$page->setCopyright()` (with the brackets).

*By the way, use* `function __construct()` *when defining an object constructor, it's better than using* `function Page()`*.*

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `this` when you should be returning `$this`.

Switch on error reporting and you will see errors about trying to `return this`.

---

Secondly, if you want to *call* a *method*, *call* it:

```
$this->listCSS();
              ^^
```

I don't know what you expect that result to be, since `listCSS()` returns `$this` (the object you're calling the method of).

Comment: Actually I updated the code I did change return this -> return $this but there is still nothing being pulled for setAppName, setCopyright, listCSS and listJS functions

Comment: How are you *calling* those method and how are you checking that nothing is returned?

Comment: require_once('controllers/pages.php');
$page = new Page;
$page->setTitle('Home');
$page->startBody();
$page->endBody();
echo $page->render('views/pages.php');

Comment: I added the index.php and views/pages.php which should clarify how the index.php or any other page is born from controller/pages.php and views/pages.php

Comment: See update. I think you need to go back to basics regarding OOP.